# How to sign R API requests with credentials

Tags: r, api, httr

I'm trying to use Hackpad's API in R. Unlike the example in [httr](https://github.com/hadley/httr/blob/master/demo/oauth2-github.r), the [Hackpad documentation](https://hackpad.com/Hackpad-API-v1.0-k9bpcEeOo2Q)
1. uses oauth 1.0 and
2. says that the requests should be signed with your credentials.

I do not completely understand how to do the 2nd part in R (with any library). I understand how to use the request, authorize, and access URLs -- but those are not provided for Hackpad (as far as I can tell).

Here is what I tried in R (to no success):

```
library(httr)
myapp <- oauth_app("hackpad",
               key = mykey,
               secret = mysecret)
hackpad_token <- oauth1.0_token(oauth_endpoint(authorize = 'https://hackpad.com/api/1.0/',
                                           request = 'https://hackpad.com/api/1.0/',
                                           access = 'https://hackpad.com/api/1.0/'),
                            myapp)
```

and also

```
req <- GET("https://hackpad.com/api/1.0/pad/k9bpcEeOo2Q/content/latest.html",
       config = authenticate(user=myuser,
                             password=mypass))
```

which tries to return the API documentation content.

Thank you for your help